# woothemes flexslider controlNav property is not hiding when set to false

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, woothemes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrWQI.png)
the problem is that the bullets at the bottom of the image aren't hidden even when their showing property is set to false

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      touch: true,
      directionNav: false,
      smoothHeight: true,
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: false,
    });
  });
```

i was expecting the bullets to hide

Comment: Sorry for anyone who tried to help i don't even know what happened but it worked, sorry again